# how to use LESS Elements in rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, less

I tried to use LESS Elements at http://lesselements.com/
I downloaded [LESS Elements](https://github.com/dmitryf/elements/zipball/master), then imported it like this:

```
@import "elements.less";
```

In my application.html.haml, I tried to use it like this:

```
.row{:style=>'height: 105px; gradient(#00F5F5, #EEE, #FFF);'}
```

I am already using twitter bootstrap, as you can see the row class above. 
But, the resulted div is pure white, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins begin with a ".".

```
.row{ style: "height: 105px; .gradient(#00F5F5, #EEE, #FFF);" }
```

You could also do this with a class, instead (which will be more efficient at runtime)

your_controller.css.less

```
@import "elements.less"
.gradient-row {
   .gradient(#00F5F5, #EEE, #FFF);
}
```

your_view.html.haml

```
.row.gradient-row{style: "height: 105px;"}
```

Comment: the first approach didn't work, how ever, adding it to a class worked! thanks very much

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it would, but I did remember seeing some less articles supposedly claiming it would. Glad to help in either case.